# Using REPLACE to change datetime with SET

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I haven't used this website before and am *very* new to SQL so please excuse any errors or if this question has been raised incorrectly - I have been asked to do something that is well outside of my remit and skill level!

I have many rows of data with a particular column - `COLUMN` - which has a `DATETIME` datatype, in a particular table - let's call it `_data`, and the data within it looks like this: `2019-11-12 17:00:00.000`

I want to replace the YY-MM-DD portion of all of the columns in this table with today's date, `2019-11-28`.

I am trying this code:

```sql
update DATABASE.dbo._data
set COLUMN = REPLACE(COLUMN,'2019-11-13','2019-11-28')
```

Which executes and informs me that every row in `DATABASE` has changed, but when I look at the data with a `SELECT` statement, it is the same as it was before. Why is this, do I need to do something different because the datatype is `DATETIME`? Google did not elucidate me and neither did w3schools or the other questions I searched for on here, but that's probably because I have no idea what I am doing.

> I am using **SQL SERVER 2012 on a Windows Server 2012 R2** box and I am running this code with SQL Server Management Studio v18.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DATETIMEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-previousversions#remarks) is your best friend here.

```sql
DECALRE @now DATETIME = GETDATE();

UPDATE    DATABASE.dbo._data
SET       COLUMN = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
                       YEAR(@now), 
                       MONTH(@now), 
                       DAY(@now),
                       DATEPART(hour, COLUMN),
                       DATEPART(minute, COLUMN),
                       DATEPART(second, COLUMN),
                       DATEPART(millisecond, COLUMN));
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a really add logic, but seems like the "easiest" method would be to use `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET DateTimeColumn = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, DateTimeColumn, GETDATE()), DateTimeColumn);
```